# how to develop a web service/application to access hyperledger-fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm a beginner of hyperledger-fabric.

I’m currently developing web service/application using `Golang`, to call hyperledger-fabric chaincode. For example, i want to create a URL by `Golang`, this URL may be like this `www.example.com/queryUser?user=abc`, and this URL will access a hyperledger-fabric chaincode which can query the funds of user named *abc*.

At present, i can set a network succesfully by running [fabric-samples/basic-network/start.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/basic-network/start.sh), and install succesfully chaincode in [chaincode_example02/go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go), and then how can i develop a web service/application to access this chaincode?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you should be using LOOPBACK REST API to build your web service application using tools like NODE.RED. Hope this helps.

Comment: My dilemma is not to build a web service, but how to access the hyperledger-fabric chaincode using Golang.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try reproduce the documentation here, but did you take a look at the [SDKs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fabric-sdks.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node) to query/invoke chaincode. But if you have to use golang, check out [fabric-go-sdk](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go).